# GitHub API - What I am doing wrong in here?

Tags: python, api, github, pygal

I am using GitHub API to plot the most stared projects. This is the code:

```
import requests
import pygal
from pygal.style import LightColorizedStyle as LCS, LightenStyle as LS

path = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'

r = requests.get(path)
r_py = r.json()
repo_dicts = r_py['items']

names, plot_dicts = [], []
for repo_dict in repo_dicts:
    names.append(repo_dict['name'])
    attr = {
        'stars' : repo_dict['stargazers_count'],
        'description' : repo_dict['description'] or "",
        'link' : repo_dict['html_url'],
    }    
    plot_dicts.append(attr)

chart = pygal.Bar(x_label_rotation=45, show_legend=False)
chart.x_labels = names
chart.add('', plot_dicts)
chart.title = 'Most popular Python Projects on GitHub'
chart.render_to_file('PopPy.svg')
```

When I run rendered file (`PopPy.svg`) it shows the following chart with no data:

[image]

I double checked the API and see if I am using wrong key for dictionaries. Everything seems to be correct but still it doesn't work as expected.

Please help me with this thank you.

Comment: `'stars'` is not a valid attribute for chart values. The key in `attr` needs to read `'value'`.

Comment: where do I find list of these valid attributes?

Comment: Haven't found an exhaustive list anywhere. The [docs](http://pygal.org/en/stable/documentation/configuration/value.html) suggest `value`, `label`, `color`, `formatter`, `style`, `node`, `xlink` and `ci`. Some of which might not be available on all chart types, e.g. `node` seems exclusive to line charts.